# use SP.UI.Dialog on page load without ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Tags: 2010, javascript, dialog

I know I can do this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(..)
}, "sp.js");
```

But I want to call `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` as soon as the page loads, without waiting for `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`.

I saw [SharePoint 2010 Modal Dialog on Page Load](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79576/sharepoint-2010-modal-dialog-on-page-load) but that says to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`.

I tried referencing the required JS files but then I get an error `Object doesn't support property or method 'get_staticObjects'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>
```

Comment: check if Script On Demand is available in 2010, if so use SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });

Comment: SOD is there but it won't work on page loading. It only works after the page has finished loading.

Comment: Try require.js, then load all necessary dependent files (sp.js, sp.ui.dialog.js) then run the code. Put all these within <head> section.

Comment: unfortunately I am trying to do this in a CEWP and can't add code to the head.

Answer (score 1):

Will need to add sp.runtime.js to this list as well..just below the init.js

Comment: Then I get the error `'IEnumerator' is undefined` and `Unable to get property 'noObjectPathAssociatedWithObject' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: I literally have a WebPart page with a CEWP pointing to an HTML file that only includes references to those 5 JS files. Just that. And when I go to the page I get those errors.